# Complementary sequence of another sequence

Tags: sequences-and-series, terminology, book-recommendation, integers

I have a infinite or finite sequence of positive integers. Let it be infinite for this example:

The infinite sequence $\{1,2,3,4,6,7,8,9,11,12,13,14,16,17,18,19,...\}$
shows that steps of $5$ are left out. So if my notation (on congruent relation) is valid, numbers that is $n\equiv 0 \mod 5$ are left out.

My question is simply if we include the numbers that where left out in the previous sequence, and put the missing ones into another sequence (creating a new sequence) like this: $\{5,10,15,20,25,...\}$, what is this last sequence called?

A complementary sequence? Or can we use the terms of set-theory, a complementary set? Im hoping to learn more terminologies of these concepts, so I just start by asking a simple question. How can I write the above with math notation?

I also ask for a good book (that is not too dry) on the subject without much advanced formulations.

Comment: The complementary part of it is a set complement. The sequence part is (it seems) the fact that you are listing both sets in increasing order. In general, sequences (of positive integers, say) can have repeated elements and can be in crazy orders, so the notion of "complementary sequence" that you have in mind here is only "obvious" for special (e.g. strictly increasing) sequences.

Comment: @Ned Thanks. Yeah, these sequences are simple and strictly increasing for each element is increasing. So in my mind they are simple to state, and not chaotic by themselves. Id like to learn the concepts of simple sequences that is not to complex and their terms thereof. Since you say I can use the set complement also, can I define the set of the first sequence for $A$ and the last set $B=A^c$, or is there a better definition?

Comment: The sequence and the set are not identical, so don't use $A$ for both (if that's what you meant). You might call the underlying set of a given sequence the "range" of the sequence, so you have the "increasing sequence whose range is the complement of the range of the given sequence." I don't know any standard term for that, nor any standard notation for the "increasing sequence of elements from some set." You could make up a symbol for the latter, use Rng($A$) for range of sequence $A$, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Complementary sequences" is the name of this phenomenon. You can read about this here:

https://www.fq.math.ca/Papers1/48-4/Mortici.pdf

After you understand the article, you can demonstrate easily that

$$NS(n)=n+1+\left\lfloor\cfrac{1+\sqrt{4n+1}}{2}\right\rfloor$$

misses exactly the squares!

Just out of curiousity, the sequence

$$Z(n)=n+1+\left\lfloor \cfrac{x}{N-1} \right\rfloor$$ misses exactly the multiples of $N$.

Answer (score 0):

The second set is the relative complement of the first set with respect to the natural numbers. If the first set is $A$, then the complement of $A$ relative to the set $U$ is written as $B = A^c = U \backslash A$.